# Specify depth for edge in NetworkX graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, traversal

I have an undirected graph for which I'd like to find the shortest path without knowing the `source` and `sink`. `NeworkX`'s `all_pairs_dijkstra_path` allows the discovery of all shortest paths without knowing source and sink, as long as it is given a length `cutoff` (measuring the depth of traversal).

Currently, every edge traversed adds `+1` to depth. Is there a way to specify the edge attributes such that

- each edge carries a weight `w` by which the path length (and shortest path) is evaluted
- each edge also carries a depth `d` by which a specified total depth terminates the path search?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the graph, you need to give each edge an attribute representing your distance:

```
G.add_edge(0, 1, distance=0.4)
```

When computing shortest paths, you can then specify that attribute such that the weighted shortest path is computed:

```
paths = nx.shortest_path(G, weight='distance')
```

`all_pairs_shortest_paths` only computes the unweighted case; however, `shortest_path` computes all pairs, too, if you don't specify the source and target node.

#### Edit

There isn't anything in networkx that fits the bill (AFAIK). However, you can create a generator for all paths between two nodes ordered in terms of total "depth" using `nx.simple_paths.shortest_simple_paths`, and then compute the shortest path based on weight:

```
import itertools
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

def path_cost(G, path, attr='weight'):
    return sum([G[path[i]][path[i+1]][attr] for i in range(len(path)-1)])

G = ...

cutoff = 3
output = dict()
for source, target in itertools.combinations(list(G.nodes), 2):
    minimum_cost = np.inf
    for path in nx.simple_paths.shortest_simple_paths(G, source, target, weight='depth'):
        if path_cost(G, path, 'depth') > cutoff:
            continue # to next source, target pair
        else:
            if path_cost(G, path, 'weight') < minimum_cost:
                output[(source, target)] = path
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, sorry for my ambiguity. In my graph, each edge has a weight and I want to respect the shortest path as such. What I'd like to be able to do is set certain edges to also have a step size - so even though it may have traversed one edge (carrying a specific weight), it walked x steps in depth. Since the search stops in terms of depth and not weight, walking one edge but with larger 'depth' terminates the search earlier. Is this clearer?

Comment: Yes, that is clearer. I have updated my answer accordingly.